# LOESS confidence intervals excessively narrow in qqplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, continuous-integration, loess

I'm having some trouble understanding how confidence intervals are calculated in `ggplot2` while using LOESS smoothing. From a few other threads, my understanding is that `ggplot2` uses t-intervals calculated based on regression standard errors, i.e., using the distance between the actual data points and the LOESS line. But I think I must be mistaken based on the confidence intervals that `ggplot2` produces. Here's example code (actually `qplot` in this case, but I think the result should be the same):

```
qplot(Year, Purposivism, data=fig1.dat, geom=c('point', 'smooth'), level=0.99, span=0.5, method='loess', ylab="Term Frequency per Million Words") +
theme_bw() +
theme(text=element_text(family="Century", size=12)) +
expand_limits(y = 0) +
scale_x_continuous(breaks = scales::pretty_breaks(n = 10)) +
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust=1))
```

Here's the resulting graph:

[image: Graph]

On the left side of the graph (say, 1920-1940) the points are tightly packed around the LOESS line, and are mostly inside the confidence intervals. But from around 1960-1980, they're all over the place, yet the width of the confidence interval seems about the same. I think I must be misunderstanding how the CIs work, because this seems unintuitive.

Thanks in advance for your help! Very happy to provide any other information that might be useful.

Comment: The shaded area is the confidence interval around the regression line, not a representation of what share of points will be expected in that range. More here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/82608/221905

Comment: That's right--thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Where you are likely confused is in the difference between confidence and prediction interval. Confidence intervals, which are used in `geom_smooth` are the predicted confidence in the estimated mean. This is a measure of how far the average of your observations will deviate at the point estimate. In `predict.lm` there is an option to add `interval = "prediction"`, which would give you the prediction interval. The prediction interval incorporates the uncertainty in the error-term from `y ~ x %*% beta + epsilon`, while the confidence interval only incorporates the fixed effect uncertainty from `y ~ x %*% beta`. I have not looked into prediction intervals for `loess` curves, and other non- and semi-parametric smoothers, but it does not seem to be implemented in `?predict.loess`

We can illustrate how `geom_smooth` estimates the confidence intervals by manual calculation. Lets start by using the most boring reproducible example. `mtcars` from the `stats` package (included in base `R`).

```
data(mtcars)
fit <- loess(mpg ~ hp, data = mtcars)
preds <- predict(fit, se = TRUE)
names(preds)
#[1] "fit"            "se.fit"         "residual.scale" "df"
```

To calculate the confidence interval, we use the standard formula as you correctly specified.

```
T <- qt(p = 0.975, df = preds$df)
lwr <- preds$fit - T * preds$se.fit
upr <- preds$fit + T * preds$se.fit
```

To create a proper plot of the confidence interval i merge all the necessary info into a single `data.frame`, while ordering the input, to ensure proper line order.

```
ord <- order(mtcars$hp)
plotData <- data.frame(lwr = lwr[ord], 
                       upr = upr[ord], 
                       fit = preds$fit[ord], 
                       hp = mtcars$hp[ord], 
                       mpg = mtcars$mpg[ord])
```

Last but not least we simply need to create the plot, and compare it to the one produced by `ggplot2`

```
p1 <- ggplot(plotData, aes(x = hp, ymax = upr, ymin = lwr)) + 
    #Data points
    geom_point(aes(y = mpg)) + 
    #Line from prediction
    geom_line(aes(y = fit)) + 
    #Points from prediction
    geom_point(aes(y = fit)) + 
    #Confidence interval
    geom_ribbon(alpha = 0.3, col = "thistle1") + 
    labs(title = "manual")
p2 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = hp, y = mpg)) + 
    geom_point() + 
    geom_smooth() + 
    labs(title = "ggplot2")
#Merge plots
library(gridExtra)
grid.arrange(p1, p2, ncol = 1)
```

Now for the output:
[image: Image of loess smoother produced by the described code]

Except for some smoothing done by `ggplot`, and the added points for the fitted values this is easily seen to be identical.

I hope this clears out how the points confidence interval is calculated.

Comment: Extremely helpful response, thank you for taking the time!

Comment: Glad i could help. :-)